# What does "function type" indicate

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

In trying to implement `std::is_function` I have run into a case where VC++ and libc++ disagree.

```
static_assert(std::is_function<int()volatile &>::value, "Not function");
```

libc++ accepts this.  VC++ fails, claiming it isn't a function.  Who is right?

In 20.9.4.1 (Table 47) it says:

```
template <class T> struct is_function;
T is a function type (3.9.2)
```

The phrase "function type" is not specified as clearly as "integral type".  I am having difficulty finding exactly what it means.  What paragraphs exactly specify what "function type" means?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[dcl.fct]/1-3:

> 1 In a declaration `T D` where `D` has the form
>
> > `D1` ( *parameter-declaration-clause* ) *cv-qualifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>* *ref-qualifier<sub>opt</sub>* *exception-specification<sub>opt</sub>* *attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>*
>
> and the type of the contained *declarator-id* in the declaration `T D1` 
>   is “*derived-declarator-type-list* `T`”, the type of the
>   declarator-id in D is “*derived-declarator-type-list* function of
>   (*parameter-declaration-clause* ) *cv-qualifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>*
>   *ref-qualifier<sub>opt</sub>* returning `T`”. The optional *attribute-specifier-seq* appertains to the function type.
>
> 2 In a declaration `T D` where `D` has the form
>
> > `D1` ( *parameter-declaration-clause* ) *cv-qualifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>* *ref-qualifier<sub>opt</sub>* *exception-specification<sub>opt</sub>* *attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>* *trailing-return-type*
>
> and the type of the contained *declarator-id* in the declaration `T
>   D1` is “*derived-declarator-type-list* `T`”, `T` shall be the single
>   *type-specifier* `auto`. The type of the *declarator-id* in `D` is “*derived-declarator-type-list* function of
>   (*parameter-declaration-clause* ) *cv-qualifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>*
>   *ref-qualifier<sub>opt</sub>* returning `U`”, where `U` is the type specified by the *trailing-return-type*. The optional
>   *attribute-specifier-seq* appertains to the function type.
>
> 3 A type of either form is a *function type*.

Paragraph 3 defines the term *function type* (note the italics). A function type can have a *cv-qualifier-seq* and/or a *ref-qualifier*. In fact, [dcl.fct]/6 explicitly addresses these "special" function types:

> A function type with a *cv-qualifier-seq* or a *ref-qualifier*
>   (including a type named by *typedef-name* (7.1.3, 14.1)) shall appear
>   only as:
>
> - the function type for a non-static member function,
> - the function type to which a pointer to member refers,
> - the top-level function type of a function typedef declaration or *alias-declaration*,
> - the *type-id* in the default argument of a *type-parameter* (14.1), or
> - the *type-id* of a *template-argument* for a *type-parameter* (14.3.1).

In other words, `std::is_function<int()volatile &>::value` should be `true`. MSVC is non-conforming if it claims otherwise.